# How to determine endpoint and create request from WSDL - c#

Tags: soap, wsdl

I need to create DHL shipment request from c# and I have got this wsdl: https://wsbexpress.dhl.com/sndpt/expressRateBook?WSDL

I am not sure what is endpoint for shipment request.

How can I call this method from c#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are working in Visual Studio, either console or web application, you need to add service reference and paste your wsdl in it.

Initiate the `wsdl` using

```
projectname.servicenamespace.servicename obj = new servicenamespace.servicenameclient();
```

Then call your services

```
obj.methodname(params...)
```